Where can I find the list of 100,000+ words for coloring materials?
From https://www.20minutes.fr/societe/langue_francaise/4081194-20240402-combien-mots-existe-langue-francaise:

selon les Immortels, le jargon des chimistes compterait plus de 100.000 mots rien que pour les matières colorantes.

Google Translate:

according to the Immortals, the jargon of chemists counts more than 100,000 words just for coloring materials.

Where can I find that list of 100,000+ words for coloring materials?

I guess you might be more successful if you ask it on https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/, as the question is very domain-specific. Maybe the claim is incorrect in the first place, or is just some sort of estimation without a list actually existing, and I think that you'll be more likely to have chemists addressing that on chemisty.SE.

Thank you, noted!
